# Script to find libraries that have a specific content type

Tags: powershell, content-type, powershell-script

I would like to know if there is a power shell script that will go through all libraries/lists on a single SP2013 farm and give me an output where a certain content type is still in use?
I want to remove certain content types added to task lists that was used for workflow purposes but not necessary any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Find-Lists-or-Libraries-fd247709):

This script takes 2 arguments:

- Web URL - This is a fully qualified URL to the site.
- Content Type Name - This is the content type name.

So using the script would look like the following:

**Find-Content-Types.ps1 "http://SPURL/SITE" "CONTENT TYPE NAME"**

*Hope it helps!*

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$webUrl=$args[0]
$ctName=$args[1]
$count=0
$site=get-spsite $webUrl
Write-Host "Starting search...." 
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach($lst in $web.lists)
    {
        foreach($ctype in $lst.ContentTypes)
        {
            if($ctype.Name -eq $ctName)
            {
                Write-Host $lst.DefaultViewUrl -ForegroundColor Yellow
                $count++
            }
        }
    }
    $web.Dispose()
}
Write-Host "Found $count lists using the content type '$ctName'." -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zdenek - work like a charm!

Comment: You're welcome.